# Conditional probability of posterior distribution for bayesian linear regression

Tags: regression, bayesian

In [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) Chapter 5.6, *Bayesian Linear Regression* is introduced. I'm confused by the following formula:

$$ p(w | X, Y) \propto P(Y | X, w) P(w)$$

- $X$ is a sample vector input data.
- $Y$ is the corresponding vector of output data.
- *w* is the scalar we want to estimate the linear function.

**How is this derived?**

My attempts to derive this result in the following:

$$ \begin{align} P(w | X, Y) & = \frac{P(w, X, Y)}{P(X, Y)} \\
   & = \frac{P(X)P(w|X)P(Y|w, X)}{P(X)P(Y|X)}\\
   & \propto P(w|X)P(Y | X, w)
\end{align}$$

- Apply the definition of conditional probability.
- Use the chain rule to expand numerator and denominator.
- Use proportionality to throw away all parts only involving $X$ and $Y$.

My derivation results in $P(w|X)$, where the book reads $P(w)$.

*Note: This example features univariate regression, whereas the book actually introduces multivariate regression. The derivation, however, should remain the same. Just change $w$ to a vector and $X$ to a matrix.*

Comment: You are formally correct. In regression, from both Bayesian and classical perspectives, $X$ is conditioned upon, which means that $P(w|X)=P(w)$. For instance, when using a $g$-prior, the variance of $w$ may depend on $X^\text{T}X$.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense. And from a Bayesian perspective, $P(w)$ is then the prior, correct? Do want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a linear regression like $Y=wX+\epsilon$, i.e., when $$\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=wX\quad\text{and}\quad\text{var}(Y|X)=\sigma^2$$the model is defined conditional on $X$, whether or not $X$ is considered as a random variable. There is thus no reason for the prior on the coefficient $w$ not to depend on $X$ and there are many arguments for dependence, one being that the scale of $X$ impacts the scale of $w$ (as, e.g., when moving from meters to kilometres in the recording of the components of $X$). The most classical illustration is Arnold Zellner's so-called $g$-prior that sets
$$p(w|X,\tau)\propto\exp\{-w^\text{T}(X^\text{T}X)w/2\tau^2\}\qquad p(\tau)\propto\tau^{-1}$$and relies on the OLS projection matrix $(X^\text{T}X)^{-1}$ as the variance of the Normal prior. In our book [Bayesian Essentials with R](http://amzn.to/2kxP1vO), this approach is the one recommended for Bayesian linear regression.